# Creating Left join method in Laravel Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have below left join in Controller, which shows all records of specific teachers in one report, and it returns all correct records. I want to use the exact same query in many other reports, so I want to create Method in eloquent Model to call it where ever I want.
**how to use this query in model** 
and **how to call it in view.**

```
public function edit(Teacher $teacher)
{
$teachers= DB::table('teachers')
->leftjoin('religions', 'teachers.religion_id', '=', 'religions.id')
->leftjoin('areas', 'teachers.area_id', '=', 'areas.id')
->select('teachers.*')
->where('teachers.id',$teacher->id)
->first();

$areas = area::all();
$religions = religion::all();

return view('teachers.report1',['teachers' => $teachers, 'teacher'=>$teachers,'areas'=>$areas,
'religions'=>$religions]);
```

Comment: Can you tell me if teacher is related to multiple religions and areas or one?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu teacher has only one religion area etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Teacher model you can do

```
public function teacherRecords(){
    $teachers= DB::table('teachers')
    ->leftjoin('religions', 'teachers.religion_id', '=', 'religions.id')
    ->leftjoin('areas', 'teachers.area_id', '=', 'areas.id')
    ->select('teachers.*')
    ->where('teachers.id',$this->id)
    ->first();
}
```

and use it like `$teach->teacherRecords();`

If I can understand, the relationship between tables/models, I can provide a better solution.

If teacher has only one religion and one area, just do it like

```
class Teacher extends Model{
    public function area()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App/Area');
    }

    public function religion()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App/religion');
    }
}
```

In Area model

```
class Area extends Model{
        public function teacher()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App/Teacher');
        }
    }
```

In Religion model

```
class Religion extends Model{
        public function teacher()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App/Teacher');
        }
    }
```

Now you can do `$teacher->area` and `$teacher->religion`

Comment: relationship between tables is one to one, teacher can have one religion, one area etc from respective table. teacher table have there id's.

Comment: @iscpreee Additionally you can specifies foreign keys to make it better.

Comment: do i need to create another controller to use above solution?

Comment: @iscpreee no that is your teacher model only. and you can use it anywhere after that.

Comment: Teacher model:
public function area(){
  return $this->belongsTo(area::class,'area_id');
 }
Area model: 
public function teachers(){
  return $this->hasMany(teacher::class);
  }
but my boss said this is not a good solution, create method to do it in teacher model only. don't create any other model except teacher. is it possible?

Comment: @iscpreee you have already a model right, you do not need to create another, you need to use the same. and refer laravel documentation, to know how good it is.https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: i used this which returns nothing in view: use App\nation;

class teacher extends Model
{
  public function nation(){
   return $this->hasone(nation::class,'nation_id');
 }

Comment: @iscpreee Can you post your model code, controller code and view code in youre question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192949/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-iscpreee).